# perl ord function in list context

Tags: perl

The `ord` function in perl returns the numeric value of a character. Can the function be invoked in a list context? Specifically, I want to decompose a string into its numeric character values (e.g., `ABC` --> `65, 66, 67`). The following command, however, does not give the expected results: `ord(split(//,$STRING))`. I could use a loop construct such as the following:

```
my @NUMERIC=();
for(my $i=0;$i<@STRING;$i++) {
  $NUMERIC[$i] = ord($STRING[$i]);
}
```

but I would like to find a one-line solution that produces list output from the function, if possible.

Comment: Invoking it in list context and invoking it with a list as its arguments are two different things. The former is possible: it still returns a scalar, regardless of the context. The latter is not; it only takes a scalar as its argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ord` you can determine the character code of only a single character. To get a list of codes from a string you can use `split` and `map` together. Like this

```
my $s = 'STRING';
my @codes = map ord, split //, $s;
print "@codes\n";
```

**output**

```
83 84 82 73 78 71
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't operate on lists, sorry.

Try this:

```
my $string = 'ABC';
my @numbers;

push @numbers, ord $_ for split '', $string;
```

Comment: `split ''` is better written `split //` to emphasize that the first parameter is a regular expression

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the `for` construct could be used like that (without explicit conditions).

Comment: Ah; I got the `// repeats last match` behavior of `s///` confused with `m//`, and wanted to disambiguate.  D'oh.